# elementor column background image not showing on live server

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have set a background image one of my elementor page section.Image is showing on the editing page but not on live server.I google to solve this problem but failed.I am desiging this website on live server.Is anyone here to help me with this?

I tried with replacing the url from elementor settting and cleaned up the cashe file and cahce pluign.

Answer (score 0):

Go to: Elementor Menu > Advanced Settings > print method > set to External File

Then Elementor Menu > Tools > Regenerate Css and data Click to regenerate

Now I can see the background images in the columns, it seems that these images are stored in the elementor .css, and when updating it stopped working.